# angular push result to controller

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

(was not sure what to have as a title, so if you have a better suggestion, feel free to come up with one - I will correct)
I am working on an angular application where I have some menues and a search result list. I also have a document view area.
You can sort of say that the application behaves like an e-mail application.

**I have a few controllers:**

DateCtrl: creates a list of dates so the users can choose which dates they want to see posts from.

SourceCtrl: Creates a list of sources so the user can choose from which sources he/she wants to see posts from.

ListCtrl: The controller populating the list. The data comes from an elastic search index. The list is updated every 10-30 seconds (trying to find the best interval) by using the $interval service.

**What I have tried**
Sources: I have tried to make this a filter, but a user clicks two checkboxes the list is not sorted by date, but on which checkbox the user clicked first.
If it is possible to make this work as a filter, I'd rather continue doing that.
The current code is like this, it does not do what I want:

```
.filter("bureauFilter", function(filterService) {
        return function(input) {
            var selectedFilter = filterService.getFilters();

            if (selectedFilter.length === 0) {
                return input;
            }

            var out = [];

            if (selectedFilter) {
                for (var f = 0; f < selectedFilter.length; f++) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                        var myDate = input[i]._source.versioncreated;

                        var changedDate = dateFromString(myDate);
                        input[i]._source.sort = new Date(changedDate).getTime(); 

                        if (input[i]._source.copyrightholder === selectedFilter[f]) {
                            out.push(input[i]);
                        }


                    }
                }
                // return out;

                // we need to sort the out array
                var returnArray = out.sort(function(a,b) {
                    return new Date(b.versioncreated).getTime() - new Date(a.versioncreated).getTime();
                });

                return returnArray;
            } else {
                return input;
            }


        }
    })
```

Date: I have found it in production that this cannot be used as a filter. The list of posts shows the latest 1000 posts, which is only a third of all posts arriving each day. So this has to be changed to a date-search.

I am trying something like this:

```
.service('elasticService', ['es', 'searchService', function (es, searchService) {
    var esSearch = function (searchService) {
        if (searchService.field === "versioncreated") {
// doing some code
} else {
 // doing some other type of search 
}
```

and a search service:

```
.service('searchService', function () {
    var selectedField = "";
    var selectedValue = "";

    var setFieldAndValue = function (field, value) {
        selectedField = field;
        selectedValue = value;
    };

    var getFieldAndValue = function () {
        return {
            "field": selectedField,
            "value": selectedValue
        }
    };

    return {
        setFieldAndValue: setFieldAndValue,
        getFieldAndValue: getFieldAndValue
    };
})
```

**What I want to achieve is this:**
When no dates or sources are clicked the whole list shall be shown.
When Source or Date are clicked it shall get the posts based on these selections. 
I cannot use filter on Date as the application receives some 3000 posts a day and so I have to query elastic search to get the posts for the selected date.

Up until now I have put the elastic-search in the listController, but I am now refactoring so the es-search happens in a service. This so the listController will receive the correct post based on the selections the user has done.

Question is: What is the best pattern or method to use when trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your data is coming from is pretty irrelevant, it's for you to do the hook up with your data source.

With regards to how to render a list:

The view would be:

```
<div ng-controller='MyController as myCtrl'>
  <form>
    <input name='searchText' ng-model='myCtrl.searchText'>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in myCtrl.list | filter:myCtrl.searchText' ng-bind='item'></li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click='myCtrl.doSomethingOnClick()'>
</div>
```

controller would be:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['ElasticSearchService',function(ElasticSearchService) {
  var self = this;
  self.searchText = '';
  ElasticSearchService.getInitialList().then(function(list) {
    self.list = list;
  });

  self.doSomethingOnClick = function() {
    ElasticSearchService.updateList(self.searchText).then(function(list) {
      self.list = list;
     });
  }
}]);
```

service would be:

```
myApp.service('ElasticSearchService', ['$q', function($q) {

var obj = {};
obj.getInitialList = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    // do some elastic search stuff here
    // on success
    defer.resolve(esdata);
    // on failure
    defer.reject();
    return defer.promise();
  };

  obj.updateList = function(param) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    // do some elastic search stuff here
    // on success
    defer.resolve(esdata);
    // on failure
    defer.reject();
    return defer.promise();
  };
return obj;
}]);
```

This code has NOT been tested but gives you an outline of how you should approach this. `$q` is used because promises allow things to be dealt with asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input danday74. Because of your answer I was able to solve the problem. I looked at your code + did a search on promise + angularjs and found this site: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-recipe-search-site-angular-elasticsearch/ which shows how to do it. But would not have found and understood the code without your input.